# Third cron field doesn't seem to work (job runs when I don't want it to)

Tags: linux, cron

I scheduled a job like this:

```
*   *    6-8  *  1-5  echo "test" >>/tmp/test.log 2>&1
```

I expect this job to run only on 6th,7th,8th, these 3 days. but today is 18th, it still runs. What is wrong with this job? What shall I do if I want it to run a some specific days?

Comment: Not sure about this, but from what you posted, the spaces/tabs between the columns are not all the same.

Comment: I tried reformatting my crontab so that every 2 fields are separated by 1 space. it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The day-of-month and day-of-week positions are OR'd, so in your example, the cron will run on the 6th, 7th, or 8th ***or*** Monday through Friday. Since the 18th is a Monday, it runs. It's not exactly intuitive.

To get the behavior I think you desire (run on the 6th, 7th, and 8th if they are a weekday), then you can do something like this:

```
* * * * 1-5 date '+%d' | grep '[678]' && echo "test" >>/tmp/test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: day-of-month and day-of-week are not exactly OR'd, right? if I use * * 6-8 * *, the day-of-week field matches every day, but it runs only on 6-8.

Comment: ahh. I just found this in man 5 crontab. Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified in the following two fields — 'day of month', and 'day of week'.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., do not contain the "*" character), the command will be  run  when
       either field matches the current time.  For example,
       "30 4 1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.

Answer (score 2):

The day-of-the-month specification (field-3; one-relative) and the day-of-the-month field (5) are both specified.  In this case, a match for either means that your crontab runs.